# How to differ abstraction from a software component

Tags: abstraction

How can we clearly differ architectural term abstraction from a software component,
can abstraction lie within a software component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstraction occurs **THROUGHOUT** software engineering - when you create a function to perform a computation, that's abstraction; when you group data and their operations into a class, that's abstraction; when you modularise your code into separate architectural components, that's abstraction.

The pattern is one of hiding the underlying complexity of a component in a simple interface - making a simple call to a function or procedure is much easier than typing all the required code each time - the function has *abstracted* that complexity.

That function might be part of a class, which is another layer of abstraction, and so on, up the abstraction ladder.

Take a look at Joel's [fantastic article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html) about leaky abstractions, which starts with an intro to the concept